# Why do I get "Unknown validator: 'MessageValidator'"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I get this error

> Unknown validator: 'MessageValidator'

I have no idea why I'm getting that.
What's wrong with my code?

```
validates :title,   
    :presence => true,   
    :uniqueness => true,   
    :length => { :maximum => 100 },
    :message => "Must be input and has to be less than 100 characters, and unique."
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try:

```
validates :title, 
          :presence => {:message => "Title can't be blank." },
          :uniqueness => {:message => "Title already exists."},
          :length => { :maximum => 100, :message => "Must be less than 100 characters"}
```

Comment: that is implicit http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness

Comment: The above link is broken

Answer (score 7):

I assume you want the message to be when the length validation fails.  You should be including message in that hash like:

```
validates :title,   
    :presence => true,   
    :uniqueness => true,   
    :length => { :maximum => 100, :message => "Must be less than 100 characters"}
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I want the same message for all cases??? Do I have to paste that to the other 2?